# Possible? A self contained html page that accesses client serial ports using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, serial-port, operating-system

Wondering if it's possible to run a client hosted html file (with scripts etc), that can access the computers serial ports.

My requirement is a portable 'applet' used to configure a serially connected device using hex data sentences - without a web server somewhere else.

i.e. send a serial request, data block is received. User manipulates it locally, then pushes it back to thecserial port with a different prefix.

Any thoughts?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible: no browser-based JavaScript engine (what you'd need to execute scripts in a HTML file) have bindings for serial port. Using hybrid frameworks such as Cordova allows you to make JavaScript bindings to native code; you would need to have a native implementation for each individual platform for Cordova to bind. There may be existing Cordova plugins to do this (depending on exactly what you need); for example, there's multiple Cordova-to-Arduino bridges.

Comment: Thanks. This what i expected,  but thought it was worth asking!